# Vue.js chart not working?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, chart.js

I'm trying `chart.js` with `vue.js`.

I've a component called `MessageGraph` that looks like this (the data etc is from the [docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-installation)):

```
<template>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</template>

<script>
    import Chart from 'chart.js';

    export default {
        created() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: '# of Votes',
                        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero:true
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

But I receive this error in my console:

```
app.c47f281….js:71222 [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: 
(found in <MessageGraph> at /Users/Janssen/Code/forumv2/resources/assets/js/components/graph/MessageGraph.vue)
warn @ app.c47f281….js:71222
handleError @ app.c47f281….js:72107
callHook @ app.c47f281….js:72939
Vue._init @ app.c47f281….js:74420
VueComponent @ app.c47f281….js:74584
createComponentInstanceForVnode @ app.c47f281….js:73779
init @ app.c47f281….js:73587
createComponent @ app.c47f281….js:75318
createElm @ app.c47f281….js:75261
createChildren @ app.c47f281….js:75386
createElm @ app.c47f281….js:75294
createChildren @ app.c47f281….js:75386
createElm @ app.c47f281….js:75294
patch @ app.c47f281….js:75753
Vue._update @ app.c47f281….js:72697
updateComponent @ app.c47f281….js:72820
get @ app.c47f281….js:73131
Watcher @ app.c47f281….js:73114
mountComponent @ app.c47f281….js:72824
./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.js.Vue$3.$mount @ app.c47f281….js:77914
./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.js.Vue$3.$mount @ app.c47f281….js:79963
Vue._init @ app.c47f281….js:74430
Vue$3 @ app.c47f281….js:74511
./resources/assets/js/app.js @ app.c47f281….js:80091
__webpack_require__ @ app.c47f281….js:20
0 @ app.c47f281….js:80854
__webpack_require__ @ app.c47f281….js:20
(anonymous) @ app.c47f281….js:66
(anonymous) @ app.c47f281….js:69
app.c47f281….js:72111 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at Object.acquireContext (app.c47f281….js:14468)
    at new Chart.Controller (app.c47f281….js:7776)
    at new Chart (app.c47f281….js:10193)
    at VueComponent.created (app.c47f281….js:2106)
    at callHook (app.c47f281….js:72937)
    at VueComponent.Vue._init (app.c47f281….js:74420)
    at new VueComponent (app.c47f281….js:74584)
    at createComponentInstanceForVnode (app.c47f281….js:73779)
    at init (app.c47f281….js:73587)
```

In my app.js I've added the component:

```
Vue.component('messageGraph', require('./components/graph/MessageGraph.vue'));
```

Then in my app.blade file I've this:

```
<message-graph></message-graph>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Seems like you forgot to set canvas context `var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext("2d");`

Comment: You should remove the laravel tag, this has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing the canvas element in the `created()` hook, which is called before your template is attached to the DOM.

To solve your problem you need to put your code into the `mounted()` hook of your component. But still, it is not guaranteed that the template is in document. So you have to use  $vm.nextTick() to ensure the DOM is ready. ([source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#ready-replaced)).

Also, I recommend using vue's [Child component refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Child-Component-Refs), which is more vue-like than `document.getElementById()` (it works too).

```js
Vue.component('message-graph', {

  template: '<canvas ref="chart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>',

  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {

      let myChart = new Chart(this.$refs.chart, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
          labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
          datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
              'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
          }]
        },
        options: {
          scales: {
            yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
              }
            }]
          }
        }
      })

    })
  }

})

let vue = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<div class="myApp"><message-graph></message-graph></div>'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.0/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```